# Software for organising and naming an archive of sounds

Tags: software, mac

I travelled by bike through India, and made audio recording. They range hugely in quality of content and sound. Unfortunately they were only recorded on an olympus digital voice recorder. However, many of them are only voice and the sound is fine, if a little compressed. I need to be able to listen through these tracks and edit the name, arrange into folders, and make notes on the decent ones, in order that I can create a compilation that I can release and the good stuff can be made public.

I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out sample organisation software. Below I have listed several free sample organisers, it's directly taken from [this page](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4676394) on an audio forum.

Windows:
 - [Aural Probe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/auralprobe/)
 - [JamSoft SampleSort](http://www.jamsoft.co.uk/)
 - [SoundManager](http://www.drums.sk/soundman.htm)

Mac:
 - [Sonicwire Mutant](http://sonicwire.com/mutant)

You can find more similar programs in the linked forum page.

Comment: Sonicwire Mutant looks great but doesn't support FLAC or WMA. My files are in WMA.

Comment: Too bad. Add that sort of info to your question such that people are able to give you an answer that suits your problem.

Comment: I found switch audio converter and clementine to be a good combination.

Comment: Great that you found a solution. Can you please post it as an answer and accept it? This will help future users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, using iTunes or Windows Media Player and updating ID3 tags as you go is probably the easiest (assuming you are using Mp3 as your format).  Then you can simply use one of the many tools that can separate files out based on their ID3 info.

Comment: [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) is another option for Windows that is a bit more friendly with formats other that MP3.

Comment: I really think I need more control than iTunes will offer.